# Tweet is not showing up in list of sent tweets

Tags: twitter

I sent a tweet but it does not show up in my sent list. I can see all my older tweets. Where could it have gone?

Answer (score 2):

Under your profile look for "drafts"

It happens to me most of the time when I use the android app :
the send process fails and closes the tweet
and then I find my tweet in the drafts